# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState after activity stopped

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is the situation I have. I have one animation which triggers an event after animation ends. That event gets a fragment manager which commits a new fragment.

The problem appears when I turn off screen while animation is still in progress. When screen is turned off activity looses it's state and on animation end when fragment needs to be committed I receive the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

My question is how can I prevent this from happening? How can I test can I perform a commit action before actually committing it?

Thank you.

Comment: Cancel the animation onPause() - the issue is you should never do fragment transitions after this, or through callbacks. Very good read: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html